# If statement based on what element is underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic troublesome website;

Wondering if I could write an if statement with jQuery or raw JS that would hide an element based on if another element is underneath it.

So something like; if an `<h1>` tag is directly beneath my div id, keep my div element present; all else `display: none;`

Comment: can try using [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint)

Comment: Given that all elements in an HTML document are "inside" other elements, what do you mean by "beneath"?  Beneath the mouse cursor?

Comment: There would be two cases; basically if a <h1> is directly below my element, I would like to keep my element; and all else I would like to hide my element.

Comment: why not just select all div and loop thru them one by one to see if it contains a h1 as direct child

Comment: Underneath... as in _after_ it in HTML source order or positioned behind it using CSS?

Comment: if it's a siblings issue, just use css and siblings selectors, no script needed

Comment: What do you mean by underneath and below, if h1 is a direct child, or if h1 is next sibling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not`, `has` and `first-child` selector:

```
$('div:not(:has(>h1:first-child))').hide();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c9emjotg/

Answer (score 1):

You could use css to hide all the appropriate divs, then use jquery to show them if they contain an `<h1>`

```js
$('h1').parent('.sometimesHeader').show();
```

```css
.sometimesHeader {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sometimesHeader">I don't have an h1</div>

<div class="sometimesHeader"><h1>H1 is here!</h1></div>
```

Comment: Wait, that doesn't even make sense! I'm an idiot!

Comment: What doesn't yeah this didn't work at all

Comment: @CaptainRon, try that again.